# Can't create GCP VM Instance in India

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

Whenever I try to create a VM Instance in Mumbai, I'm getting this message

**"The zone 'projects/spartan-acrobat-288909/zones/asia-south1-c' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later."**

I tried creating it in a different zone in many other different times but in never worked. I have no problem creating a VM Instance in any other countries/zones.

Answer (score 2):

The error that you are receiving does not pertain to your account specifically, it is a limitation on the Google side where the specific zones in Mumbai are full. Most probably because there are a lot of users in Mumbai that uses GCP.  You can check this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/1003347/gcp-no-resources-available-in-asia-south1-c-since-a-month) to see possible solutions and a more detailed explanation.